# How to find out selected radio option, when android:radiobutton="@null" in android?

Tags: android, android-view, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am creating a set of radio options where the radio buttons are removed, and I would like to know which option is selected.

Here is the code

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/languages"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/english"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/langtext_english"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@null" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bahasaIndonesia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/langtext_indonesian"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:button="hide"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

I don't want to show the radio button, but I would like to know which option is selected. onCheckedChangedListener doesn't work as there is no  button. How to do this?

When the option is touched or clicked, I would like to show a Toast.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        langChosen = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.languages);
        langChosen.setOnClickListener(new RadioGroup.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast abc = new Toast(getContext());
                abc.makeText(getContext(), v.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
```

Comment: "I don't want to show the radio button, but I would like to know which option is selected." If you don't show the button, how does the user know, which option is selected?

Comment: @Alex I plan to show it by "bolded" option. Which ever option is selected, it will be of bold text.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned

> I don't want to show the radio button, but I would like to know which option is selected. onCheckedChangedListener doesn't work as there is no button.

I would not say that is true. The `RadioGroup` still registers changes of the checked radio button. The `android:button` attribute of `RadioButton`just represents the button you see next to the text/content of the radio button. You still can register to click events of the radio button element itself.

Could it be that you just forgot to call `show()` on your toast, so you think it's not working?

I supply a tested solution for you here. Let me know if it works for you too.

```
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.languages);
    group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            RadioButton b = (RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, b.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Note that `MainActivity.this` must be replaced with your corresponding context.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the OnClick method with the two buttons, then the method is called, use the ischecked() method to detremine which of the buttons is checked.

Comment: I started doing that, but the onClick() method gets the parameter of type View. So I am struck.

Comment: check the id of the view, its probably the button. view is a superclass of radiobutton! you can cast the parameter to radiobutton, if the id is the same!